# Visual studio solution mix with Git project and TFS project

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have started a VS2017 solution with 3 project in TFS Server.
After few days I have added one more project from GitHub to my VS2017 solution and in TFS Server as well. Now there are changes in GitHub repo which I want to merge in my project.

So is there is a way to use both Git and TFS on single VS solution for different projects different with source control?

Comment: Are you looking to mix TFVC, or are you just trying to do pure Git Submodules in a TFS backed Git repo?

Comment: I want my 3 project to use TFVC and 1 Project to use Git(Hub). Because 3 project are develop in close source environment and 1 project is develop on open source environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  could [Use Git and TFVC repos in the same team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/team-projects)

> In Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 and above, a project
>   administrator can add a Git repo to a **team project** created with Team
>   Foundation Version Control (TFVC). You can also add a TFVC repo to a
>   team project created with Git. This allows you to adopt a new version
>   control system while preserving all the data in your team project.

There should be a local git repo corresponding to your remote github repo or tfs hosted git repo. You could add a remote repo in a selected local git repo from **Team Explorer-- Settings -Repository Settings**

[image]

After binding with two remote git repo one for GitHub, one for TFS; you could simply pull down the changes in GitHub to your local git and  then push/sync changes to your remote TFS git repo.

Comment: Actually I don't find this Repository Settings in my VS2017 with TFS 2017. Am I missing any extension?

Comment: I don't have any git repo currently all I have is one Solution with 4 projects in TFS. One is added from GitHub but not as git repo.

Comment: @CodeOverFlow Sorry for the later reply, actually you could either add a git repo to cover the solution.  Check if  the single project  from have .git or not, if there are , you need to move it. Another way is directly  [Migrate from TFVC to Git], only use one type of source control , this will  be more easily to track.

Comment: @CodeOverFlow You could also create a auto builds to  sync the code. One triggered when a change is made in GitHub, and the other when a change is made in TFS. Detail ways  please refer Martin's blog:  https://nkdagility.com/open-source-vsts-tfs-github-better-devops/

Comment: This answer does not cover the original question at all. The question was not about the simultaneous use of **TFVC** and **Git** in the same **DevOps project**, but the simultaneous use of **TFVC** and **Git** in one **project in Visual Studio**, specifically in a solution-type project where one project uses TFVC and the other project uses Git (eg a local repo).